# A goodness of fit test for two discrete distributions with unequal variance?

Tags: variance, categorical-data, goodness-of-fit, validation

I have a computer simulation in which a virtual agent end up in different areas of a layout based on several factors. There are 18 conditions, so the data (you can find the csv file for a toy dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tewmrdvv0qftddh/toy_example1.csv?dl=0)) would look like this:

[image: toy_dataset1]

If I collapse the datapoints into bins, where each bin is one of the areas, the data would look like this:

```
x0 <- c(3,3,5,5,2) # computer simulation
```

Note that if I would be to repeat the simulation, it would produce exactly the same results.

Now I would like to validate this model having human subjects going trough the same conditions, but I run into two sets of issues:

1. the first issue is due to the fact that the dataset is discrete and small (there may be less than 5 counts in a bin, and that's a problem for a Chi-Square Goodness of Fit test), also there may be ties. After some online digging I found two options:

   - a permutation test
   - a Cramer-von Mises test of goodness-of-fit (see this [paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011/RJ-2011-016/RJ-2011-016.pdf))

I thought the Cramer-von Mises test of goodness-of-fit test could work, so I ran it with made-up data for *one human subject* and I get the following result:

```
x0 <- c(3,3,5,5,2) # computer simulation
x1 <- c(4,2,5,4,3) # subject 1

library(goftest)

cvm.test(x0, ecdf(x1))

>Cramer-von Mises test of goodness-of-fit
>Null hypothesis: distribution ‘ecdf(x1)’

>data:  x0
>omega2 = 0.14667, p-value = 0.4106
```

So far so good. But now let’s say I would like to have *more than one human subject*, let’s say four of them:

```
x2 <- c(3,3,5,2,5) # subject 2
x3 <- c(2,2,5,6,3) # subject 3
x4 <- c(3,2,5,6,2) # subject 4
```

Now I run in the second set of issues:

2. on the one side I have a single computer simulation, on the other side I have data from four subjects. Should I take the mean of the results for the human subjects? Then would my data still be “discrete”? Or should I run my simulation four times? But I would get always the same results, so the variance between the two datasets would be different.

Any ideas? Maybe I should change the design and have more levels for my factors, so that I have more trials and the bins get bigger?

Comment: If your computer results are always the same, you don't appear to have something you could regard as a random variable. If your human results differ, that might be regarded as a random variable (perhaps). However your sample sizes are so small I don't see much value in this test. Indeed very large samples would also be a problem, suggesting a hypothesis test is the wrong tool. When you say you want to "validate" your results, what (conceptually) are you actually trying to show/find out?

Comment: @Glen_b Our algorithm is based on the interaction of a number of factors but is indeed deterministic. What we would like to show is that this deterministic algorithm models human behavior (which is not deterministic) reasonably well, so that the algorithm could be used to plan the layout of, let's say, a conference center.

Comment: An ordinary goodness of fit test does not answer the question "does this deterministic algorithm models human behavior reasonably well".

Comment: @Glen_b, that's good point, thank you. How about building a confidence interval based on human data and see if the computer simulation results are falling within the CI?

Comment: It's better to formulate your question in meaningful terms rather than trying to guess at what the right statistical solution might be. In this case it sounds like your simulation may have established a model for the human behavior; that the behavior may deviate randomly from the model; and you want to assess those random deviations.  Does that really require any kind of test, or would it be better to find ways to characterize and quantify those deviations?

Comment: @whuber I see your point, thank you.